# SQL Query Expanding Each Row Every Int. In Range Between COL_A and COL_B

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL Server has a TABLE. Both columns are integers, but represent dates in the form YYYYMM. I'd like to query this table and return a third column which, for every row, includes an integer in the form of YYYYMM for every year/month in the range of the two columns.

Here's the TABLE:

```
+------------+------------+
| beg_YYYYMM | end_YYYYMM |
+------------+------------+
|     201802 |     201805 |
|     201711 |     201801 |
+------------+------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+------------+------------+----------------+
| beg_YYYYMM | end_YYYYMM | month_in_range |
+------------+------------+----------------+
|     201802 |     201805 |         201802 |
|     201802 |     201805 |         201803 |
|     201802 |     201805 |         201804 |
|     201802 |     201805 |         201805 |
|     201711 |     201801 |         201711 |
|     201711 |     201801 |         201712 |
|     201711 |     201801 |         201801 |
+------------+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: My advice would be, for the purposes of this query, convert all your data into `date` datatypes - that way you can take advantage of the `datetime` functions available. You can then convert the results back to you `unusual` int format.

Answer (score 3):

Use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select beg_YYYYMM, end_YYYYMM,
             convert(date, convert(varchar(255), beg_YYYYMM) + '01') as dte,
             convert(date, convert(varchar(255), end_YYYYMM) + '01') as end_dte
      from t
      union all
      select beg_YYYYMM, end_YYYYMM,
             dateadd(month, 1, dte),
             end_dte
      from cte
      where dte < end_dte
     )
select beg_yyyymm, end_yyyymm, 
       year(dte) * 100 + month(dte) as yyyymm
  from cte
 order by dte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6cd4da798e75218bcd10c5689f3bbd7c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Much more elegant than mine.  I bow my head in shame.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think I would actually deploy this but I wanted to know what it would look like.  If you create a TVF that does the ugly work it isn't too bad.  I used Aaron Bertrand's DateDim [code](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) with a quick modification to just get first of the month dates between the two dates that are passed in.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.tvf_MonthRange (@beg_YYYYMM int, @end_YYYYMM int)  
RETURNS @Results TABLE   
 (month_in_range int)
AS  
BEGIN  

--Have to convert ints to dates
    DECLARE @BegDate DATE; 
    SET @BegDate =  DATEFROMPARTS(CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(@beg_YYYYMM AS varchar(6)),1,4) AS INT), CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(@beg_YYYYMM AS varchar(6)),5,2) AS INT), 1);

--This needs to be the second day of the month for the code below to work.
    DECLARE @EndDate DATE;
    SET @EndDate =  DATEFROMPARTS(CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(@end_YYYYMM AS varchar(6)),1,4) AS INT), CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(@end_YYYYMM AS varchar(6)),5,2) AS INT), 2);

    INSERT INTO @Results
    SELECT (DATEPART(YEAR, d) *100) + DATEPART(MONTH, d)
    FROM
        (
          SELECT d = DATEADD(DAY, rn - 1, @BegDate)
          FROM 
          (
            SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @BegDate, @EndDate)) 
              rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
            FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
            CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
            -- on my system this would support > 5 million days
            ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
          ) AS x
        ) AS y
    WHERE DATEPART(DAY, d) = 1;

    RETURN;
END
```

Then you can call it like this.

```
DECLARE @Months TABLE (beg_YYYYMM int, end_YYYYMM int)
INSERT INTO @MONTHS SELECT 201802, 201805 
INSERT INTO @MONTHS SELECT 201711, 201801 

SELECT *
FROM @Months m
CROSS APPLY dbo.tvf_MonthRange(m.beg_YYYYMM, m.end_YYYYMM) mr ;
```

It is bad idea Monday right?

Answer (score 0):

A solution using a tally table which may be faster on larger data sets.

```
with dates as(
select 
    201501 as beg_YYYYMM
    ,201504 as end_YYYYMM
union all
select '201711', '201801'
union all
select '201807', '201812'

),

--Tally table
ctedaterange AS (
SELECT top 15
    rn = Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1
FROM sys.objects a  
)

SELECT
    dates.*
    ,months_in_range = convert(varchar(6), Dateadd(mm, rn, cast(cast(dates.beg_YYYYMM as varchar(8)) +'01' as date)), 112)

FROM dates
    cross join ctedaterange

WHERE  
    rn <= Datediff(mm, cast(cast(dates.beg_YYYYMM as varchar(8)) +'01' as date), cast(cast(dates.end_YYYYMM as varchar(8)) +'01' as date))

ORDER BY 
    beg_YYYYMM
    ,Dateadd(mm, rn, cast(cast(dates.beg_YYYYMM as varchar(8)) +'01' as date))
```

[Here's the db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bf29869f1bc5db9cdf1db996cffcb6ba)